# How to organize variable IDs that depend on each other in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm creating a database for all the Magic the Gathering cards...
The card table looks like this:

- cardID
- name
- text
- rarityID
- colorID
- editionID
- other columns ...

the same card can appear on multiple editions, and in some unique cases, in a different edition it will have a a different rarity.

The only way I know how to do it would be to create one new card entry for each edition the card appears.
But sometimes the same card appears in 10+ editions without any change (at least not on what is relevant for this database), and I would be creating lots of unnecessary entries.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: can you expand more on your concern? what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: You could have a "default" edition ID, which gets used when the specific edition ID doesn't exist. But this will make all queries more complicated (you could hide it in a view, though).

Comment: I just want to avoid creating useless entries in the table.
So I would just use editions like (1,2,3,4) but don't now how to use it with the variant rarities

Comment: @user2540765 Step #1 is to identify the values that *must be identical across all versions*, if any. If anything about the card changes, this must be handled "per version". At some point it might be viewed that there is no single card that is identical across versions, but there is a specific card archetype - although it differs in each (or any particular) version. Do not worry about "wasting space" here; worry about capturing the requirements precisely.

Comment: in a different edition the usual cards only have changes in images and/or rules (both not relevant in this case) the only change that concerns me is the rarity one, that is not common but may happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on the feedback in the comments, this is what I would recommend (it still might miss changes, but I think it's a fair start). Make sure to capture everything in the domain model! It's easy to change data later .. if you have it.

```
Cards    |-These are common to the card across all Editions*
 CardId, CardName, DeckColor, ..
 |-PK-|  |-Possible Key?  -|

Editions
 EditionId, EditionName, ReleaseDate, ..
 |-PK   -|  |-Key?   -|

CardEditions        |-These are unique per Card/Edition
 CardId, EditionId, Rarity, Rules, ..
 |-PK           -|
 |-FK-|  |-FK   -|
```

(*Bill Karwin points out that there are multi-colored cards, arg! To capture that requirement, float a CardsColors relationships much like CardEditions. If the color changes across editions as well, then I just want to cry ..)

I've laid out a simple schema above (arguably not fully normalized). However, for further reading look up "Slowing Changing Data" as there are a few different ways to handle it.

---

Updates for Comment:

How find a card for a specific edition, say we know the card name and edition name:

```
SELECT * FROM Cards c
JOIN CardEditions ed
  on ed.cardId = c.cardId
JOIN Edition e
  on e.editionId = ed.editionId
WHERE c.cardName = 'Some Awesome Card'
AND e.editionName = 'Ultimate'
```

Note that if the CardName and EditionName were used as Primary Key (PK) and in the corresponding FK - instead of the surrogate CardId/EditionId - then we could have possibly avoided a join entirely. There is great debate as to which approach is better. I use surrogate keys to avoid compound PK's except in join tables (e.g. CardEditions) as I like to keep queries simpler. However, this still leaves using/having an EditionId surrogate key ..

Possible Key (or "Key?") means that I suspect this field should be treated as a Key as well - that it should have a Unique Constraint (and possibly Index) applied. A relationship can have multiple Keys, where a Key is the set of columns required to *uniquely identify a record*. The Primary Key is just the "selected" Key that is normally used for this purpose.

Note that this model is not fully normalized, by the very fact that there is more than one Key for a relation; however, I've found it most productive to be consistent with surrogate keys and define secondary constraints. This also is a result of the fact that I like to treat records as entities which drive the model.

Comment: It looks like a good solution, I'm pretty new to MySQL, so just to confirm, I would use an INNER JOIN when I need to get the full card information for a specific edition?
And what do you mean by Possible Key and FK? Thank you.

Comment: That pretty much sums it up, I don't know how to declare the foreign keys, but I guess I can search it up, thank you.
PS: I can't use card name as a primary key because I will use this database in a Portuguese version too and the people who translated Magic to Portuguese decided that giving different cards the same translated name would be a good idea.

Comment: @user2540765 In that case I'd try to have CardName (English, canon) and a LocalizedCardName separate .. for just one (non-English) language they can live in the same relation, but for multiple languages this would just be expanded to another relation.

Comment: This is a good solution to comply with [Fourth Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form), which is the problem with the OP's original solution.  BTW, you need an additional table for the **color** attribute, because some MtG cards can be multi-colored, IIRC.

Comment: @BillKarwin Shows how much I know MtG. I've added a note into this answer.

Comment: @BillKarwin yeah, I'm going to use a color table too, at first I was not going to store the color information, since I will have cost stored like 1RGB (1 colorless, 1 red, 1 green, 1 black) and could take color from here, but there is one exception (maybe more, don't remember) where the card cost is 2R, and is states it's colorless =/  
And the card color never changes, doesn't matter the edition.

Comment: @user2540765, well I was referring to the color of the card itself, not the color of mana cost.  http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Multicolored

Answer (score 0):

Understand that MySQL is a **relational** database and that to properly leverage its power, you need to relate objects together.  So the first thing you need to do is to understand what your different objects are and how they may relate to each other.  From your description, you have mentioned at least two objects: cards, and editions.

So I think that means you need two tables to start with, `cards` and `editions`, but how do they relate?  If there is a one-to-many relationship (i.e. each edition could have many cards, but each card belongs to only one edition) you could just have a foreign key in cards for the edition id.  But in this case it seems that you have a many-to-many relationship.  This is traditionally accomplished by adding a third table to explain the relationship.  So in this case you might add a `cards_to_editions` table, which would consist solely of two columns, the card id and the edition id.  These would both be foreign key keys to their respective tables and would form a compound primary key for the table.

You could also add properties to the cards_to_editions table if there were any properties specific to the relationship itself (like it seems "rarity" might be in this case).